# Apply template with xml data

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

We use XSLT to render our webpages

what i am trying to accomplish is render a template with xml data:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$itemview/items/item">
        <xsl:variable name="productitem">
          <productpreview product="{self::node()}" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($productitem)" mode="shop"/>
        <!--/.item-->
      </xsl:for-each>
```

Template:

```
<xsl:template match="productpreview" mode="tshop">
  <div class="test">
    <xsl:value-of select="@product/itemcode" />
  </div>        
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result the template gets rendered but the xml structure is gone, i only get data when i do `<xsl:value-of select="@product" />`, and this data seems flatted.

Is it possible to send xml structure with apply-template? how should i do this?

Comment: I think doing `<xsl:value-of select="@product/itemcode" />` never makes sense as an attribute can't contain an element node. You will need to explain in more detail how your input looks, which data you want to store in your variable and which one you want to output.

Comment: I quite don't understand your example. Is your input XML an XSL stylesheet? What is the result your would like to obtain?

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks, i'm new to xslt and was wondering if this fits the xslt convention, but apperently not. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have neither shown your XML input nor the result you want but assuming you simply want to store and process the `item` elements then I would do that as

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$itemview/items/item" mode="shop"/>
```

instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="$itemview/items/item">
        <xsl:variable name="productitem">
          <productpreview product="{self::node()}" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($productitem)" mode="shop"/>
        <!--/.item-->
      </xsl:for-each>
```

and then simply

```
<xsl:template match="item" mode="shop">
  <div class="test">
    <xsl:value-of select="itemcode" />
  </div>        
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

instead of

```
<xsl:template match="productpreview" mode="tshop">
  <div class="test">
    <xsl:value-of select="@product/itemcode" />
  </div>        
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't see a need for a variable or at least not for a result tree fragment, you seem to want to process the original input.